Flutter add different types to a List<Map>
I would like to add multiple types of classes to a List to use it in a DataTable later on. My desire is to sort the specific columns and use buttons inside of it later on to do some actions. How do I add multiple types of classes to a List?
Therefore I want to add Icons, Strings, Integers, Widgets to it, is this possible?
The commented lines are the ones which doesn't work.
What do I write to add Icons or Buttons to it?
Has anyone a solution for it?
class _MyBooksState extends State<MyBooks> {
List<Map> _books = [
{
  //Icons: Icon(Icons.warning),
  "book": "Harry Potter",
  "author": "Goethe",
  "id": "1",
  //"btn": Switch(
  //   inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
  //   inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
  //   value: true,
  //   onChanged: (value) {},
  // ),
},
{
  //Icons: Icon(Icons.warning),
  "book": "Harry Potter",
  "author": "Goethe",
  "id": "2",
  // "btn": Switch(
  //   inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
  //   inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
  //   value: true,
  //   onChanged: (value) {},
  // ),
},
{
  Icons: Icon(Icons.warning),
  "book": "Harry Potter",
  "author": "Goethe",
  "id": "3",
  // "btn": Switch(
  //   inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeColor: Colors.white,
  //   activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
  //   inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
  //   value: true,
  //   onChanged: (value) {},
  // ),
}
];
int _currentSortColumn = 0;
bool _isSortAsc = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
    child: MyAppBarNotificationsView(
      title: "Books",
      callback: () {},
    ),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: [_createDataTable()],
  ),
);
}

DataTable _createDataTable() {
return DataTable(
  columns: _createColumns(),
  rows: _createRows(),
  sortColumnIndex: _currentSortColumn,
  sortAscending: _isSortAsc,
 );
 }

 List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
 return [
  //DataColumn(label: Text('type')),
  DataColumn(
    label: Text('book'),
    onSort: (columnIndex, _) {
      setState(() {
        _currentSortColumn = columnIndex;
        if (_isSortAsc) {
          _books.sort((a, b) => b['book'].compareTo(a['book']));
        } else {
          _books.sort((a, b) => a['book'].compareTo(b['book']));
        }
        _isSortAsc = !_isSortAsc;
      });
     },
    ),
    DataColumn(label: Text('author')),
  //DataColumn(label: Text('icons')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('id')),
  // DataColumn(label: Text('btn'))
];
}

List<DataRow> _createRows() {
return _books
    .map((connection) => DataRow(cells: [
          //DataCell(Text(connection['icons'])),
          DataCell(Text(connection['book'])),
          DataCell(Text(connection['author'])),
          DataCell(Text(connection['id'])),
          // DataCell(Text(connection['btn']))
        ]))
    .toList();
}
}


"Doesn't work" how?  What error do you get?  List<Map> is shorthand for List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>, so the Maps already should accept any types for the keys and values.  That said, I don't personally think that storing heterogeneous types is a good idea.

Please do not vandalise your posts. Especially not if you got an answer by another user.

The problem is in declaration of List of Map. In Flutter, you declare the List of Map like List<Map<String, dynamic>>. In this way you can add "key" : "value" pairs and add different types and objects such as Strings, Integers, Icons, Buttons etc..

List<Map> is shorthand for List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>.

Do you have an example how I can do it?
When i declare: List<Map<String, dynamic>> _books = [ ....
I only get the error:
type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' of 'function result'

Here is an example of populating list with one book:
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _books = [
{
"icon": Icon(Icons.warning),
"book": "Harry Potter",
"author": "Goethe",
"id": 1,
"btn": Switch(
inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
activeColor: Colors.white,
activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
value: true,
onChanged: (value) {
// Handle switch change
},
),
},
];
